# How to Download files in bulk from box.com with collaboration and file info by single rest api call?

Tags: java, rest, integration

In [box.com](https://www.box.com/), Do they have any Rest API so, we can get all files from It's Folders and Sub-Folders with below information in a single API call?

1. Owner of the files.
2. Version information of the files.
3. Content of the files.
4. Collaboration information of the files

In API documentation one [Download zip archive](https://developer.box.com/reference/get-zip-downloads-id-content/) Rest-API is available but It's not useful in my case as it not contains all above information and we don't want to make multiple API calls due to performance issue.

OR, Is there any open source connector available which can help us to get this information from [box.com](https://www.box.com/) ?

We will really appreciate if some one can help us on this.

Comment: It confirmed by them as they do not have such kind api. for more information follow below link.    https://support.box.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360049949574-How-to-Download-files-in-bulk-with-collaboration-and-file-info-by-single-rest-api-call-

Comment: Your "question" is not stated as a question.